# Real duration of audios played through browsers

Tags: audio

I need to play 4 audios through a browser web.
These audios last 150ms, 300ms, 450ms and 600ms.

I don't care about latency (if an audio is played 100 ms after it's not that important for my purpose).
But I do care about the duration of these audios: is the 150ms audio last exactly 150ms or there is an error due to the audio board or other components?

I know for sure that there is an error (I see a test using a Mac).
My question is: can anyone show me a paper, an article or anything that talks about the duration and test different setting or tell me if this error is always (Windows, Mac, old device, new device) very small (less than 10ms for example).

In other words: if I play an audio of 100ms how long does it really last (100ms? more? less?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what manner is the sound not lasting the correct amount of time?

Does the beginning or the end get cut off?
Does the sound play back slower or faster than it should?

In my experience, I've never heard an error with playback rates caused by the browser or sound boards. But I have come across situations where a sound is played back with a different audio format than which is was encoded. For example, a sound encoded at 48000 fps played back at 44100 fps will take longer to execute, but will be very close to the original in pitch (maybe about a 1/2 step lower). I recommend as a diagnostic step to confirm the audio format used at each end. How to do so will depend on the systems being used.

Comment: My idea was based on the fact that image presentation suffers from latency and duration variability so I thought the same can occur for audio. So I haven't an answer for your first question :(. Thx very much for the answer and for the advise! But can I ask you what do you mean for step?

Comment: The phrase "1/2 step" lower: I was using a musical term that refers to notes in a musical scale. I'm writing from my experience with the way Java handles audio data, not from working with browsers (only have done a little with audio on browsers), and so am speculating as to what might cause variability based on what I've seen cause issues in the Java realm.